# PostgreSQL: ERROR: syntax error at or near "clear"

Tags: postgresql

I use `psql` to connect to the PostgreSQL database on terminal. If I run a simple select query,

```
select count(*) from my_schema.my_table;
```

I get the error:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear"
LINE 1: clear`

UPDATE:

I cannot even execute a simple select query like `select * from my_schema.my_table;` or `select * from my_table;`. It gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "my_table" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from my_table;
```

Comment: I suppose 'my_schema' or 'my_table" is named "clear" is not it?

Comment: @rmuller: No! They have absolutely different names. I cannot understand what `clear` refers to. This title does not appear anywhere.

Comment: whats the content of `.psqlrc`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: How can I check it? I am connected to remote machine on terminal.

Comment: `cd && cat .psqlrc`

Answer (score 0):

Did you login into right database.

The error 'relation "my_table" does not exist' seems cause by wrong database selection.

For example:
psql -h localhost -p 5435 -U myuser -W <>